# Remove element in drop down list after being selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a table in my database which stores cars. Then in my system, there's a drop down list of the cars in the database (element in drop down : Car A,Car B,Car C ). Lets say if User A choose Car B, Car B will not longer available for the other user to choose when they login. My question is, how to make the car is not available to be selected anymore? Is there any page that I can refer? How to remove an element in the drop down list after being selected? If you don't understand what I mean, Feel free to ask me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: But that car won't be removed from the database, right? What's the meaning of this selection? Is this "my car" or "car I'm renting"?

Comment: You might want to look at using Application State http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/ms178594(v=vs.100).aspx as an option

Comment: @CloneClose So you'll probably have a "rented cars" table. When retrieving the car list for this dropdown, make a join with this table to retrieve only the available cars. =)

Answer (score 0):

i think in database you can maintain field for Isselected  which contain Boolean value. if user select that car update database with value true. when load the drop down menu select cars which 
  Isselected =false

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is use ajax to control the list of cars that are available. It would be possible to "push" information when a user selects a car.

The flow would be something like this:

1. User A selects a "Nissan Altima"
2. Through Ajax the information is sent to the server
3. The server stores the association between User A and "Nissan Altima"
4. the server "pushes" the information to User B
5. User B's screen updates and the list is updated

You can accomplish ajax "push" from one user to another using Comet.

- [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)
- [Reverse Ajax](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-reverseajax1/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your database table *should* have a field named IsReserved (or something similar), then your drop downlist would be populated with the query:

```
SELECT * FROM Car Where IsReserved=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create another **temp table** where you can save the `CarID` or `CarCode` along with `sessionID` When user selects a car from drop down (You can fire Event on selection an item )

on this event save the carID & SessionID in the Temp Table

Table Structure

```
 CarTempTable
    CarID xxx
    SessionID varchar(x)
    Date   datetime
```

once you have CarID & SessionID in this table then you can query you main table for other user with a query like

```
SELECT CarID, CarName FROM Cars WHERE CarID NOT IN (SELECT CarID FROM CarTempTable WHERE SessionID <> "'+ SessionIDofUSER+'";
```

in the above approach you have to make sure you clear the temp table entries for the particular session on session end.

This approach should work for you

EDIT: If it is car renting then it is good to have an extra column in you table which says if car is available or not based on if user books the car. you can use this with above temp table as i am not sure how you take booking is it by payment or by other means