# Value in dropdown menu (Removed)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu which retrieve value from database,

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" 
   DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Plate" DataValueField="Plate" 
   Height="45px" Width="141px">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Connection %>" 
   SelectCommand="SELECT [Plate] FROM [CarTab] WHERE ([Model] = @Model)">
      <SelectParameters>
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList4" Name="Model" 
              PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
      </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This will retrieve Plate Number from database. As admin, admin will select any plate number to be given to user to rent. Here is the question, how to remove the plate number after be given to user? For example, Plate A is selected, and after admin hit the button of SAVE, the Plate A is not available to be selected again. Plate A will be removed from the list. 
I hope you can help me by giving some clues, ideas and suggestions. Looking forward to hear from you soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mark the plate number as removed by a flag in the database.

Keep a bit field in your database table. Set it to 1 when the admin selects a plate number.

Update it on the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" 
   DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Plate" DataValueField="Plate" 
   Height="45px" Width="141px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged" >
</asp:DropDownList>

protected void DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged"(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var connectionString = "your connection string from some configuration";
    var updateCmd = "UPDATE [CarTab] SET Rented = 1 WHERE ([Model] = @Model)";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(updateCmd , connection);
        command.AddWithValue("@Model", DropDownList4.SelectedValue);
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

In your `SelectCommand` check with a where clause if the plate number is already rented out.

```
SELECT [Plate] FROM [CarTab] WHERE Rented = 0 and ([Model] = @Model)
```

Comment: Im sorry, i don't really get you.

Comment: how to set to 1 when admin select the plate num?

Answer (score 1):

When `Save` button is pressed, Mark the Plate the plate as removed, by setting `flagfordelete` column as true, and change the query of loading plate to exclude the marked plates.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have similarities between your question & other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362421/remove-element-in-drop-down-list-after-being-selected/12362832#12362832).
Approach will vary if one one admin will manage the booking other wise you have to look for similar approach as described below

Approach if you want to adapt

I would suggest you create another **temp table** where you can save the `CarID` or `CarCode` along with `sessionID` When user selects a car from drop down (You can fire Event on selection an item )

on this event save the carID & SessionID in the Temp Table

Table Structure

```
 CarTempTable
    CarID xxx
    SessionID varchar(x)
    Date   datetime
```

once you have CarID & SessionID in this table then you can query you main table for other user with a query like

```
SELECT CarID, CarName FROM Cars WHERE CarID NOT IN (SELECT CarID FROM CarTempTable WHERE SessionID <> "'+ SessionIDofUSER+'";
```

in the above approach you have to make sure you clear the temp table entries for the particular session on session end.

This approach should work for you

EDIT: If it is car renting then it is good to have an extra column in you table which says if car is available or not based on if user books the car. you can use this with above temp table as i am not sure how you take booking is it by payment or by other means

Answer (score 1):

When the Save button is pressed by the user, you will have to check again the availability of plates in the database. If the selected plate has been removed from the Admin then you can show proper message to the end user otherwise run the code and save the record. I hope you get my  point.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what kind of backend database you are using so my comments will apply to SQL Server.

Add a `bit` data type column to the CarTab table named 'IsSelected'. change your SQL SELECT to `SELECT [Plate] FROM [CarTab] WHERE ([Model] = @Model) AND IsSelected=0`. Initially set the 'IsSelected' field to `0` for all records. When a plate is selected, UPDATE the `IsSelected` field to `1` using the primary key for the record. Then only the records that have not been selected will populate your `DropDownList`.

There can be concurrency issues with this solution if 2 users have the data entry screen loaded and one selects a plate. The other user's screen will not be current.

Comment: Hi Dave. Thanks. Your solution looks interesting. How to update the IsSelected field to 1?

Comment: @ColorShadow - You will need to send a SQL UPDATE command in code that handles the click event of your Save button. Something like `UPDATE CarTab SET IsSelected = 1 WHERE id = @RecordID`. The id field should be your primary key for the CarTab table and the @RecordID would need to be the primary key value for the selected plate. If the plate is the primary key then `UPDATE CarTab SET IsSelected= 1 WHERE Plate=@PlateValue`. You will need to adjust some of this to your situation but it should point you in the direction of a possible solution.

Comment: Hi Dave, why when I key in 0 in column isSelected 0, it says the was not recognized of this cell

Comment: @ColorShadow - You don't say what type of database you are using so I can really comment on your question. These are the kinds of issues that you as a developer need to work out on your own.